# How do zerg counters mines

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm platinum level so I don't think I have enough micro to split units when I see a mine about to fire.

In early game, I tried zerglings & roachs, speedlings seem to be the best for me because I can send some suicides to deactivate alone mines, then progressively go forward.

But since there are marines with mines, I can often barely trigger the later. I tried to provoke friendly fire but this occurred not to worth the change for me (after comparing losses on replay).

Mine drops are not really a problem for me if (when I'm well aware), now I simply do at least a spore and a spine on each mineral line, and pull off my drones when the drop is coming.

In late game, I dispatch overseers then some lings when I see mines, but I still break my teeth on defenses with mines.

So the question is:

**In zerg platinum level, how to counter widow mines in early, middle, late game ?**

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58619/starcraft

Answer (score 7):

Widow mines is a stress-factor for most. So here are some tips for you as a Zerg player!

**Early game:**

- Send zuicide Zerglings to deal with the Widow Mines. If you think the
  Terran might have Widow Mines in the field, always keep 2 Zerglings
  ahead of your army move path. (If you Bane-Bust, send 1-2 Zergling up
  the ramp to trigger the mines)
- Bring 2 Overlords with your army, or send Overlords to where you
  might think there is a mine or more. (it takes two mines to kill one Overlord)

**Mid game:**

- Same as early game.
- Use overseers together with ranged units. Always get the speed
  upgrade. (TIP: Use the "Hold" function often when engaging the Terran defences with mines - by this, your ranged units will not follow the Terran units back into the mines, but instead kill the mines since you have an Overseer or two, maybe three)
- If you go for Mutas, always magic box them when attack the Terran!

**Late game:**

- Shouldet be a problem for you.
- But same as the previous points.

Comment: Not mentioning infestors in late game

Comment: And hydras to outrange mines

Answer (score 3):

All ways be scouting so you can always get the surround.

Being a zerg you need to have very good map awarness. Spread your overlords, put lings on attack paths, and keep your mutas active. The key is knowing where and when the Terran is going to attack you.

If you know this you can do all the difficult micro before an engagment. Spread out in a big ring around a good open spot on creep and attack as soon as the Terran walks into the ambush.

This will let you crush Terrans untill you hit high diamond/masters players. After that you need to keep a sharp eye out during the engagment and split the zergling groups being targeted by the mines. This is possible because you know the first lings are the ones that are going to be targeted so you split around them when the mine becomes visible prior to firing. Very difficult though. Also I recomend going very bane heavy, lots of banes are countered excelent splitting and that shouldn't be an issue for you yet.

Also subscribe to this guy :P

Answer (score 1):

I will not go into much detail, since the macro orentated answers are short and simple.

Early game:
Spine crawlers (outrange) 
Single zerglings (to triggers one line)

Mid game:
Overseers go first to tank damage and reveal them.
More spines and spores to protect your multiple bases

Late game:
As long as you are not massing fragile units like mutalisks, overseer + any support will take them out quite nicely. Note that mines are short ranged, so long range units like swarm hosts and broodlords can force the terran to fall back.

Answer (score 0):

I think these answers are a great way to deal with surprise widow mines but if you know one or more of your opponents is building a massive amount of widow mines i would suggest one of the following:

- Hydras with range upgrade outrange widow mines. Just keep an overseer with a hydra control group and you will be able to stay out of range and shoot widow mines from a distance. Keep your overseer close enough to reveal the mines and and a-click behind the mines with your hydras.
- Ravager corrosive bile will also outrange widow mines. You don't need a detector for this one. You can see the widow mine if you look carefully.
- Infestor Fungal Growth will reveal burrowed widow mines. It takes 3 fungal growths to kill them.

Another little tidbit about widow mines- there is a small delay before they fire. You should see a red line appear when you get too close. If you pull back fast enough you won't get hit.